# How to implement UIDAI Aadhar APIs in asp.net c# and Android?

Tags: c#, android, xml, web-services, api

I am developing application which require Aadhar card authentication using C#.Net MVC. 
I had already refer most of blogs for implement Aadhar card API in C#.Net, but unable to find appropriate solution for it.
Can you please help me regarding this issue.

Comment: Have you read their Authentication API pdf?

Comment: @MAdeelKhalid if you have the link to pdf do you mind sharing it?

Comment: Aadhaar Authentication API pdf https://uidai.gov.in/images/FrontPageUpdates/aadhaar_authentication_api_2_0.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution at [aadhar birdge APIs](https://www.aadhaarbridge.com/).

Fully documented solution for Aadhar integration using seamless platform (Authentication and e-KYC and MOU) in your Desktop application and Android SDK and Android Sample Application with JSON request.